# Do four pieces of identical cyclic quadrilateral having atleast two angles equal to 90 degree makes a square?

Tags: geometry

So I was thinking if four pieces of congruent cyclic quadrilateral having atleast two angles 90 degrees then when all four pieces are joined can always makes a square (Orientation of pieces are allowed)

I mean when a square is cut by two perpendicular rays through centre at particular orientation makes four identical cyclic quadrilateral pieces so I was thinking if the converse is true

Comment: You also need two sides comprising a right angle to be equal between them.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you take 4 $ 1 \times \sqrt{2} $ rectangles, how do you make them form a square? $\quad$ Note that in your "square is cut by two perpendicular rays", you have that **2 of the consecutive sides at a $90^\circ$ angle are congruent**, which is what allows you to then "rotate the figure by $90^\circ$ and stick them together, thereby forming a square".

Comment: I get the point but what about quadrilateral having no side parallel to each other they it may hold?